# Conditionally remove text from string in R

Tags: r, text, replace

I have this vector in R `c("993540002_prih_10_new_10153_2.pdf", "993540002_prih_11_old_13369_3.pdf", "993540002_prih_12_older_18217_4.pdf")`

I'd like to edit it to

```
c("993540002_prih_10_new_2.pdf", "993540002_prih_11_old_3.pdf", "993540002_prih_12_older_4.pdf")
```

In other words, remove number between two underline symbols including one underline symbol. But do it only in case that there is no "prih" text before underline.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the replacement would make it difficult to transform. If you can be more assertive of the file name format, then we can make it easier. If we assume files are named like

```
number_word_number_word(_number)_number.pdf
```

Where we would like to remove the part in `()`, then we can do

```
x <- c("993540002_prih_10_new_10153_2.pdf", "993540002_prih_11_old_13369_3.pdf", "993540002_prih_12_older_18217_4.pdf")

gsub("(\\d+_\\w+_\\d+_\\w+)(_\\d+)(_\\d+\\.pdf)", "\\1\\3", x)
# [1] "993540002_prih_10_new_2.pdf"   "993540002_prih_11_old_3.pdf"  
# [3] "993540002_prih_12_older_4.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, if your file names always end with "xxxxx_y.pdf" and you want to remove the "xxxxx" part, you can avoid tricky regex by using `substr()` to replace the positions and  `gsub()` to remove it. For example:

```
test <- c("993540002_prih_10_new_10153_2.pdf", "993540002_prih_11_old_13369_3.pdf", "993540002_prih_12_older_18217_4.pdf")

substr(test, nchar(test) - 10, nchar(test) - 5) <- "xxxxxx"
 # [1] "993540002_prih_10_new_xxxxxx2.pdf"   "993540002_prih_11_old_xxxxxx3.pdf"   "993540002_prih_12_older_xxxxxx4.pdf"

test <- gsub("xxxxxx", "", test)

# [1] "993540002_prih_10_new_2.pdf"   "993540002_prih_11_old_3.pdf"   "993540002_prih_12_older_4.pdf"
```

When comparing it to your desired data (`want`):

```
want <- c("993540002_prih_10_new_2.pdf", "993540002_prih_11_old_3.pdf", "993540002_prih_12_older_4.pdf")

all.equal(test, want)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

A `sub` used with a capture group may work here. Don't know about *"in case that there is no "prih" text before underline"*, because it's always true in the example.

```
Str <- c("993540002_prih_10_new_10153_2.pdf", "993540002_prih_11_old_13369_3.pdf", 
"993540002_prih_12_older_18217_4.pdf")
```

```
sub("(.*)_\\d+(_\\d+\\..*)", "\\1\\2", Str)
[1] "993540002_prih_10_new_2.pdf"   "993540002_prih_11_old_3.pdf"  
[3] "993540002_prih_12_older_4.pdf"
```